# PYOMO optimization on multi-dimensional data

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I am trying to see how I can implement multi-dimensional optimization in PYOMO. Here is a brief explanation of the problem.

Cost = AX + BY + CZ (Here A, B & C are one dimensional time series parameters and X, Y & Z are one dimensional time series decision variables.)

I have to implement the above expression for n number of times for different units. There are linked constraints that help n-unit optimization more productive than individually optimizing the units.

The most crudest way is to create the cost function as follows,

COST = (AX + BY + CZ) + (A1X1 + B1Y1 + C1Z1) + .....+ (AnXn + BnYn + CnZn)

But the constrains are too many that if I go beyond two units the code is becoming a mess. Is there a way where I can make A, B, C , X, Y & Z as matrices so that every column represents a unit?

And the final expression can still be

Cost = AX + BY + CZ

Any help can be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Why don't you multi-index everything ( time x unit ).  From what you say above X, Y, Z are *not* one-dimensional variables, they are 2d (time x unit), right?  As I see your problem, I'd start with 2 sets, `time_period`, and `unit_ID` and go from there, it should fall into place.  There are many examples on this site of multi-index `pyomo` models.  Give it a try, and post whatever code you have if you get stuck, which is the traditional way of asking a question.  :)

Comment: Thank you. Will try the multi-index approach and will update here how things are flowing.